# Ubuntu 13.04 boot time is 1 min 20 seconds!

Tags: boot, 13.04, swap

I have a lenovo z370 notebook (i5...6GB RAM..750 GB HDD) and running Windows 7 dual boot with ubuntu 13.04.
The boot up is very slow and I have tried many things in this forum (for e.g disabling unnecessary services upon boot up,preload,reduce swappiness etc etc)

PLease can someone have a look at the bootchart and the dmesg output and let me know your suggestions?

This part of o/p message is of interest:

```
[    3.131275] kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
[    3.131375] EXT3-fs (loop0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode
[   38.953398] Adding 262140k swap on /host/ubuntu/disks/swap.disk.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:262140k 
[   38.983848] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   39.032443] EXT3-fs (loop0): using internal journal
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include how fast Windows 7 boots on that machine?

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off your swap, because it seems to be taking forever to load.

You can do this by deleting the line in /etc/fstab that contains your swap partition.